# Problems when using global class object array's variables

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm new to using global class object array, I'm trying to create the same but I have errors.

```
Object.cpp

class Foo {
    public:
       bool a = false; 
};



Funtion.cpp

Foo* foos[10]

void DoSomething1(int index) { // index input is given sequentially from 0 to 10

if ( foos[index]->a == false) {
    foos[index]->a = true;
    DoSomething2(index);
}
```

But if statement occurs once when index is 0. 
When index is 1, "foos[index]->a" is already true. 
But this is not what I want.
I want all of "foos[index]->a = false" before entering if statement.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: although the problem may be obvious, you should post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure you want an answer? Global variables tend to be a bad idea, so remaining new to them might be the better option in the long run. (On the other hand, you could rephrase this question in terms of a local variable -- I don't see anything in the problem that requires the variable to be global.)

Answer (score 1):

you don't really create any `Foo`, you only create a array of `Foo*`, so accessing `foos[index]->a` is actually undefined behavior.

although depends on what you really want, change it to `Foo foos[10]` and it should work.